# mapping through array of objects and accessing object values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pick a value from array of object and the values can only be from first object.
Firstly i have a array of objects like this:

```
items [
  [
    {id: 1, title: "title1", imgUrl: "https://someimage1"},
    {id: 2, title: "title2", imgUrl: "https://someimage2"}
  ],
  [
    {id: 1, title: "title1", imgUrl: "https://someimage1"},
    {id: 2, title: "title2", imgUrl: "https://someimage2"}
  ],
  [
    {id: 1, title: "title1", imgUrl: "https://someimage1"},
    {id: 2, title: "title2", imgUrl: "https://someimage2"}
  ]
]
```

I am planning to display the title and img url on the page. I am using react and this is what i have tried so far:

```
items.map(item => {
   //here i enter each array of the big array individually

   //here i will enter first object of the give array
   console.log('ITEM:', item[0])
})
```

in console.log i get this:

```
ITEM: {id: 1, title: "title1", imgUrl: "https://someimage1"}
ITEM: {id: 1, title: "title1", imgUrl: "https://someimage1"}
ITEM: {id: 1, title: "title1", imgUrl: "https://someimage1"}
```

but I need to get each `title` and `imgUrl` so in my `.map()` I do this:

```
    items.map(item => {
       //here i enter each array of the big array individually

       //here i will enter first object of the give array
       console.log('ITEM:', item[0].title)
    })
```

but I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

I don't understand why I thought I would be able to use dot notation to access whatever key in the object you would like:

```
for more context:
            <div>
                {
                    items.map((item) => {
                        return <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div>
                                    <p>{item[0].title}</p>
                                    <img src={item[0].url}/>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    })
                }
            </div>
```

MY SOLUTION TO THE ABOVE PROBLEM

SO i have spend some time messing around with this issue and this works for me:

```
            items.map((item) => {
                return item.map ((x, index) => {
                    if (index === 0) {
                        return <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div>
                                    <p>{ x.title }</p>
                                    <img src={x.url}/>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    }
                })
            })
```

Still not sure why my initial idea `item[0].title` not work without having nested map() function

Comment: Your "array of objects" in the first code example isn't valid syntax, and looks like if it _was_ valid syntax it would be an array of arrays.  You might want to review/revise that, otherwise it is going to be hard to understand the conditions your are dealing with...

Comment: Please create a reproducible code snippet (by clicking the `[<>]` button) of your issue. From the details you've given, I can't reproduce your error

Comment: Also, in your last piece of code `item[0].url` should be `item[0].imgUrl`. I'm also pretty sure that you need to wrap your JSX in parentheses when writing multiple lines.

Comment: I added an update to my answer below in response to your update of the question with your solution. I do not believe you should be nesting loops in this case (Additionally your use of `.map()` without returning a value in all callback iterations is considered an anti-pattern and I provided alternatives). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try using quotes around the keys:

```
items [
  [
    {"id": 1, "title": "title1", "imgUrl": "https://someimage1"},
    {"id": 2, "title": "title2", "imgUrl": "https://someimage2"}
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Update Based on OP updating Post:**

> Since map builds a new array, using it when you aren't using the returned array is an anti-pattern; use forEach or for-of instead.
>   Signs you shouldn't be using map:
>   A) You're not using the array it
>   returns, and/or
>
> B) **You're not returning a value from the callback.**
>
> [Further reading on .map() via Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Furthermore nesting 2 loops in such a way will force twice as many iterations as it will still run length times.

If you need to access a sub element and know its index or key then use that value by:

`array[index]` or `object.key` and use a single `map()` (example in full snippet)

If you do actually need to loop over every element (due to some condition not expressed in your question) instead use:

`.find()` (*single elements*)

or `.filter(elm => elm === 'someValue')` (*multiple elements*)

or `.reduce()` (*multiple elements*) with mutating elements as you go

or even `.forEach()` (*multi elements*) with performing additional functions outside of array building (you will need to push to something like `let loopArray = []`)

**Continue Original Answer]**

Move the ul tag outside the map statement and change url to imgUrl.

Keep in mind if `items` is generated via async then you will also need to validate `items` before using `map`, something like:

```
{(items && items.length) && items.map(item=>{
    /*code*/
)}
```

Working Snippet (without async check):

```js
const SomeComponent = () => {
    const items = [
        [
            {id: 1, title: "title1.1", imgUrl: "https://p7.hiclipart.com/preview/917/362/567/halloween-trick-or-treating-double-ninth-festival-illustration-halloween-design-elements.jpg"},
            {id: 2, title: "title2", imgUrl: "https://someimage2"}
        ],
        [
            {id: 1, title: "title1.2", imgUrl: "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/silhouette-cat-dog-on-white-600w-671156590.jpg"},
            {id: 2, title: "title2", imgUrl: "https://someimage2"}
        ],
        [
            {id: 1, title: "title1.3", imgUrl: "https://jngnposwzs-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Transparent-OrangeWhiteCat-768x1030.png"},
            {id: 2, title: "title2", imgUrl: "https://someimage2"}
        ]
    ];
    return (
        <div>
                <ul>
                    {items.map((item,index) => {
                        return(
                            <li key={String(index)}>
                                <div>
                                    <p>{item[0].title}</p>
                                    <img style={{width:'10%'}} src={item.imgUrl} alt={item.title}/>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <SomeComponent />,
    document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id='react'></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```